# Using the return data outside its function

Tags: jquery, ajax, function

Below is the code I am working with, my goal is whenever the user clicks the button with a class name '.view_all'. I want to use the `data` that is returned using ajax and put it inside this `line $(this).parent('div').siblings('.body_wrap').html(data);` I have tried the code below but it is not working.

```
$('.view_all').click(function (event) {
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'ajax/return_data.php'
     }).success(function (data) {
         $(this).parent('div').siblings('.body_wrap').html(data);
     });

 });
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Your question title and the content conflicts...

Comment: Note that using `.success()` was deprecated in v1.8: using `.done()` is now the recommended method.

Comment: @user2310422 Did the solution mentioned below work for you?

Answer (score 2):

`this` is your issue, `this` inside the ajax success callback is not the DOM element as you thought, it is jqXHR object instead. There are many ways to get around this, simplest way is to just cache `$(this)` externally and use it inside the callback. try:

```
$('.view_all').click(function (event) {
    var $this = $(this); //Cache it here
     $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'ajax/return_data.php'
     }).success(function (data) {
          $this.parent('div').siblings('.body_wrap').html(data); //use it
     });

 });
```

Another way is to set the `context` property of ajax settings.

```
$('.view_all').click(function (event) {
     $.ajax({
         context:this, //set up context
         type: 'POST',
         url: 'ajax/return_data.php'
     }).success(function (data) {
          $(this).parent('div').siblings('.body_wrap').html(data); //Now 
     });
 });
```